# Length of list in jinja template, where the list is the result of a DBSession.query

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I find the length of a list of objects in a jinja template when the list of objects has been created by querying a database?

I thought `There are {{ items|length }} items in this category.` would work, but items is a result of:

```
items = db_session.query(Item).filter_by(category_id=category.id)
```

and I get the error

> TypeError: object of type 'Query' has no len()

Obviously, I could calculate the length separately and pass into `render_template()`, but I wondered if there was a better way?

Any help from the community would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items` object is not a list yet, it is an unprocessed `Query` object as you see in the error. You can use `Query.all()` method to get a list of items:

```
items = db_session.query(Item).filter_by(category_id=category.id).all()
```

After that `length` filter can be applicable.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I hadn't realised that .all() was missing. Weird how I could use the unfinished query to loop through the objects in jinja (even though it was unfinished) but length filter didn't work.

Comment: @SimonOtter It's possible: `Query` object works as generator, you can iterate through it without calling `all()`. This feature can also be used in jinja templates, so your loop code worked well.

Comment: I imagine this is not applicable if `items` is very very large.

Answer (score 2):

Use `{{ items | count }}` in jinja template

Answer (score 0):

Try to add loopcontrol extension

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
```

Then

```
{% for item in items %}
{{loop.length}}
{% break %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your type oqueryset to list

items = list(db_session.query(Item).filter_by(category_id=category.id))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).